# Wiring for a westinghouse electrical motor?

Tags: wiring, induction-motor, split-phase

I've got an electric split-phase motor (no capacitor) with a centrifugal switch.

#### Specs

Westinghouse electric motor manufactured in 76.
RPM 1725/1140
1/2 HP
115V 60Hz
Thermally protected L Type

It seems to me that the terminals are bypassed as the power cord is directly connected to the motor.

When plugging the motor I hear a humming sound and I have to hand turn the shaft to make it rotate (any direction).

That tells me that there is a problem with the start winding. So, I checked the centrifugal switch, cleaned it with sandpaper and still no automatic starting of the motor.

Here's the schematic of the motor as I see it since there is no schematic printed on the chassis.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOezpr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are 2 terminals for plugging a kind of molex connector.

I don't know how to proceed from here.

Should I make connectors to connect wires between them?

Note than SW2 have a side not connected to anything!

Here's a table of all the motor interconnections between them with their resistance:

```
+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+
|        | Green  | Yellow |   Red    | Orange | Black  |
+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+
|  Blue  |    -   |    -   |     -    |    -   |    -   |
+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+
|  Green |        |   2.4  |    4.3   |    0   |    -   |
+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+
| Yellow |        |        |    5.6   |   2.4  |    -   |
+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+
|   Red  |        |        |          |   4.0  |    -   |
+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+
| Orange |        |        |          |        |    -   |
+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+
```

A - indicates infinite resistance, i.e no short circuit

Also, testing each motor input against the motor casing gives an infinite resistance.

The previous schematic shows the actual condition I got the motor and it used a bypass with a power cord.

I see that terminal A3 have a cut green wire so I guess that would be the same green wire from the motor connected with the line BLACK input.

Also, for terminal B1 the cut wire is yellow so this would be the same yellow from the motor and this would be connected with the line WHITE input.

The next schematic shows what it would have been before the "hack".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0Wj4R.png)</sup>

Comment: Add the windings to the schematic, and mention at least their DC resistances. I think it's likely the start winding will be connected via the centrifugal switch to an external start capacitor.

Comment: About the windings, I am not sure which wires go to each of them...

Comment: You have the motor. We don't. Do you have a multimeter?

Comment: Yes I have a multimeter. Since the green and yellow wires are connected to the power line I'm assuming that is the RUN winding. On that winding I get 2.4 ohms. For the start winding I'm assuming it would be the blue and red wires and I get no reading (infinite resistance, not connected).

Comment: According to your measurements the Start winding is open circuit. That would prevent your motor starting without a physical turn. I wonder if that's why you were given it?

Comment: It might be a good idea measure the resistance from each motor terminal every other terminal.

Comment: Also check the resistance between each terminal and the motor housing.

Comment: @CharlesCowie : I added the resistances

Comment: The usual fault with this kind of motor is that a bit of dust gets into the centrifugal switch.   It takes a bit of disassembly and cleaning.   Compressed air helps.

Comment: @Whit3rd : I've done the cleaning and also sanded the contact points.

Comment: I've corrected the question in light of further findings

Answer (score 1):

With the given information and discussion, I think the motor will operate with the following connection. The capacitor may not be needed. It the current in the start coil can be measured during start and it is relatively low with a capacitance value used for similar Hp motors, it might make sense to try a direct connection from the switch to the power line. There would be a risk of burning out the winding fairly quickly if it is designed for use with a capacitor.

Various electrical diagrams for washing machine are available on the internet. Some show motors that use a start winding with no capacitor and some show a capacitor. The extra centrifugal switch is shown on some as switching a function external to the motor. The extra contact on the starting centrifugal switch is shown as feeding power to an external function when the motor is up to speed.

[image]

Comment: It is what is setup right now and not an assumption. ;)

Comment: So, what do you suggest for additional connections ? Is there missing connections ? Is the motor wired correctly for the START winding to work?

Comment: Are you sure that a capacitor is needed? This motor does not seem to require one?

Comment: If you want it to start without, hand turning the shaft, in the same direction every time, you need a capacitor.

Comment: Do you think that someone else might have changed the wiring on this before you got it? The arrangement seems unusual.

Comment: I've disassembled all the connections to be left with only the motor itself and made some discoveries. I've updated the question.

Comment: The motor terminals are being bypassed by having the power cord directly connected to the motor as displayed in the diagram.

Comment: I revised the drawing. I still wonder about the capacitor being switched over to the being across the power line in parallel with the run winding. I don't think that a motor starting capacitor would not be able to tolerate that.

Comment: There was no capacitor on the motor casing. I think this is a split-phase inducing motor so it does not need a capacitor. Besides, I am pretty sure the other wires (Blue and Black) should be doing something. I'll add another schematic with the missing terminal inputs as I discovered they were used before the power cord "hack".

Comment: Motors that are mounted inside another enclosure like a heating or air conditioning equipment housing often have a capacitor separately mounted in the equipment housing. If the motor is split phase, there is a problem with the yellow and red wires connected to the centrifugal switch. I asked before if someone else could have changed the wiring before you got the motor.

Comment: The only apparent change is the power cord bypass. All the other connections to the centrifugal switch appears genuine. I've finished updating the question with an additional diagram and more text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52319/discussion-between-charles-cowie-and-stecy).

Comment: At the top of your drawing the "power" label refers to what part exactly ?

Comment: That represents the 115V connection, but I made an error with that.

Comment: I revised the answer per discussion and corrected the drawing.

Comment: Alas it is not working. Motor still hums... I've tried different size of capacitors (88-108, 270-324)...

Comment: Since this is a two-speed motor, you can be pretty sure that there is (or was) a third winding that is now not connected or open. It may not be worthwhile doing much more with the motor unless you can measure current and perhaps power. You could connect the start winding without a capacitor and see what happens.

Comment: With or without a start capacitor produces the same effect --> humming

Comment: I am out of ideas.

Comment: I will try with smaller capacitor and see how it goes. After that, I'm declaring the start winding burnt or defective.